# migrate Azure Devops artifacts to GitHub packages

Tags: azure-devops, github-packages

Is there any simple way to migrate Azure Devops artifacts to GitHub packages? We have few artifacts which need to be migrated. Are there any tools available to do this?

Comment: Yeshwanth Did you  get anything on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to perform the migration operation.

```
dotnet tool install gpr -g
gpr push MyFakePackage.1.0.0.50.nupkg --repository https://github.com/MyRepo/my-repo-name
```

These two are the simple two lines of syntaxes to follow for migration.

Comment: Pasting some code doesn’t explain what’s going on. It’d be great if you could share some documentation or why/what this does

Answer (score 0):

I expanded upon @TadepalliSairam's solution a little bit here: https://josh-ops.com/posts/github-packages-migrate-nuget-packages-to-github-packages/. This is a post detailing a script that migrates `.nupkg` files to GitHub Packages.

Basically, you have to use `gpr` since it rewrites the `<repository url="..." />` element in the .nuspec file in the .nupkg before pushing.

`dotnet nuget push` isn't capable of doing this and you will receive a `400` error right now:

```
dotnet nuget push \
  -s github \
  -k ghp_pat \
  NUnit3.DotNetNew.Template_1.7.1.nupkg

Pushing NUnit3.DotNetNew.Template_1.7.1.nupkg to 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/joshjohanning-org-packages-migrated'...
  PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/joshjohanning-org-packages-migrated/
warn : Source owner 'joshjohanning-org-packages-migrated' does not match repo owner 'joshjohanning-org-packages' in repository element.
  BadRequest https://nuget.pkg.github.com/joshjohanning-org-packages-migrated/ 180ms
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
```